# Immersions of locally ringed spaces and locally closed image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, locally-ringed-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of locally ringed spaces. In [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817832/223002), the first definition below is suggested.

1. Say $f:X\to Y$ is an $R$-immersion of locally ringed spaces if it's a topological embedding and for all $x\in X$, the canonical homomorphism $O_{Y, f(x)}\to O_{X,x}$ is surjective.
2. Görtz & Wedhorn define $f$ to be an immersion (of schemes, but still) if it's a topological embedding with locally closed image and for all $x\in X$, the canonical homomorphism $O_{Y, f(x)}\to O_{X,x}$ is surjective.
3. [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IO) defines $f$ to be an immersion if it's locally closed, i.e a closed immersion followed by an open immersion.

Following the stacks project's definition of immersion (3), the linked answer, [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816288/what-is-a-subscheme#comment1691939_817832), and [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816288/what-is-a-subscheme#comment1691947_817832), make the following assertions.

1. An $R$-immersion is an immersion iff it's locally of finite type.
2. $R$-immersions are stable under base change.
3. An $R$-immersion is an immersion iff its image is locally closed.

**Question.** How to prove assertion 3?

I ask because in the $C^p$ category, the fact $C^p$ embeddings have locally closed image is a consequence of the local structure of constant rank maps, and for nice schemes I think this follows from ZMT.